# Access process.env in environment.ts file created from the angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an angular-cli application (angular version 4.0.0). I want to be able to access my environment variables in the environment.ts file created from the cli.

Example:

```
export SOME_VARIABLE=exampleValue
```

When I build my angular app I want "exampleValue" to be populated in the SOME_VARIABLE field.

```
// environment.ts

export const environment = {
    production: false,
    SOME_VARIABLE: process.env.SOME_VARIABLE
};
```

Unfortunately, process.env isn't available in this file. How can I gain access to it?

Comment: If you can't find any built in way, you probably need to [eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) and configure the webpack [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about eject

Comment: There are some workarounds here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4318

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this is to create a node script, which replaces a place holder.

This can be done with [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) from npm.

A solution can look like this:

1. > npm install replace-in-file --save-dev
2. Create a place holder

   ```
   export const environment = {
     production: true,
     version: '{BUILD_VERSION}'
   }
   ```
3. Create node script to replace the place holder (replace.build.js in root folder)

   ```
   var replace = require('replace-in-file');
   var buildVersion = process.env.BUILD_NUMBER;
   const options = {
     files: 'environments/environment.ts',
     from: /{BUILD_VERSION}/g,
     to: buildVersion,
     allowEmptyPaths: false,
   };

   try {
     let changedFiles = replace.sync(options);
     console.log('Build version set: ' + buildVersion);
   }
   catch (error) {
     console.error('Error occurred:', error);
   }
   ```
4. Execute this node script in your build process f.e. in gulp

   ```
   gulp.task('updateVersion', function (done) {
     exec('node ./replace.build.js', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
       console.log(stdout);
       console.log(stderr);
       done();
     });
   });
   ```

Now you can use `environment.version` in your app.

Comment: I don't think add `gulp` is a good solution. keep it simple. I don't want to add too many things any more. It makes things complex

Comment: @novaline gulp is only an example. Do this with node. Do you have better/simpler suggestions?