# How to dynamically assign an environment variable to a angular cli project using Docker?

Tags: docker, angular-cli

I am having angular cli project and node project running two seperate docker containers.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

# We label our stage as 'builder'
FROM node:carbon as builder

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY . .

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --aot --build-optimizer --environment=test

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

## Copy our default nginx config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From 'builder' stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The node container URL is stored inside environment.ts (angular).

Environment.ts file

```
declare var require: any;
const pack = require('../../package.json');

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_URL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  socket: 'http://localhost:3200',
  appName: pack.name,
  version: pack.version,
  envi: 'test'
};
```

Node **API_URL** is taken during the build time of angular project. But I want to modify the environment variable during the docker run command. ( i.e ) I want to dynamically add environment variable value to the environment.ts file during docker container runtime

Such as, 
docker run -e API_URL=192.168.10.147:3000 -p 4200:80 --name=angular angular_image

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `process.env.ENV_NAME`?

Comment: **process.env** is one of the solutions. But it is not possible to directly modify in the environment.ts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497373/access-process-env-in-environment-ts-file-created-from-the-angular-cli

Comment: A more general approach can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608055/running-a-bash-script-before-startup-in-an-nginx-docker-container/54508601#54508601

Answer (score 24):

I'll try to summarize the solution I've worked out with a colleague developing an Angular app, to solve exactly this problem. To better illustrate the solution, I start by including a depiction of the dev folder tree for our angular application (folder names are in square brackets), each relevant element of which is described below:

```
+---[my angular cli project]
¦   ¦
¦   +---[src]
¦   ¦   +---[assets]
¦   ¦   ¦   +---[json]
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---runtime.json
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦  
¦   ¦   ¦   ..other angular application assets files ...
    ¦   ¦   
¦   ¦   ...other angular application source files...
¦   ¦
¦   +---[dist]
¦   ¦   ...built angular files
¦   ¦
¦   +---[docker]
¦   ¦   +---[nginx]
¦   ¦   ¦   +---default.conf
¦   ¦   +---startup.sh
¦   ¦
¦   +---Dockerfile
¦
... other angluar cli project files in my project ...
```

In your angular cli project configuration data that need to be replaced at runtime with the values of environment variables are kept in a static json file in the application assets. We choose to locate this for instance at `assets/json/runtime.json`. In this file, values to be replaced are handled like the `${API_URL}` variable in the following example:

**./src/assets/json/runtime.json**:

```
{
  "PARAM_API_URL": "${API_URL}"

  ...other parameters...
}
```

At runtime, the angular code will read the value of `PARAM_API_URL` from this file, whose contents will have been modified at runtime with environment values as explained below. Technically, the json is read by one Angular service by means of http that is, the web application performs a HTTP GET operation to itself to the URLs of the static asset json file above.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyComponent {

    constructor( private http: Http ) {
    }

    ...

    someMethod() {

        this.http.get( 'assets/json/runtime.json' ).map( result => result.PARAM_API_URL ).subscribe( 
            api_url => {
                ... do something with the api_url 
                eg. invoke another http get on it ...
            }
        );
      }

}
```

To create a docker container that performs the environment replacement at runtime startup, a script `startup.sh` will be put inside it (see `Dockerfile` below) that, at container startup peforms an evnsubst on the above file before launching the nginx web server:

**./docker/startup.sh**:

```
echo "Starting application..."
echo "API_URL = ${API_URL}"
envsubst < "/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/json/runtime.json" > "/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/json/runtime.json"
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

As shown below, the Dockerfile performs the following operations: after copying the compiled angular files in `./dist`), then defines the `startup.sh` script as a CMD starting point (the *host* `/dist` folder is COPYed in `/usr/share/nginx/html`, that's why this is the path used to locate the runtime.json file mentioned in the envsubst invocation above). Note that, differently from your Dockerfile, here we don't include the build stage of the angular cli sources, instead, the `ng build` is supposed to have been performed by the developers before the container image creation - and the result of such build is expected to be found in the `./dist` folder. This is a minor difference for what concerns the solution to the problem at hand, though.

**./Dockerfile**:

```
FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

## Copy our default nginx config
COPY docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html

## startup.sh script is launched at container run
ADD docker/startup.sh /startup.sh
CMD /startup.sh
```

Now, when you build your container you can run it with:

```
docker run -e "API_URL=<your api url>" <your image name>
```

and the given value will be replaced inside runtime.json before launching nginx.

For completeness, though not relevant for the specific problem, I include also the `docker/nginx/default.conf` file to configure the nginx instance

**./docker/nginx/default.conf**:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  sendfile on;

  default_type application/octet-stream;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This should be the accepted answer. After some fiddling around, I got it to work! One tip I'd like to add. is doing the http rquest to the 'assets/json/runtime.json' file on the application initialization. Using an APP_INITIALIZER provider (enough documentation to find elsewhere) should be a breeze.