# Angular 16 dynamic API URL docker

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to add a dynamic url for my angular app during docker runs.

```
FROM node:18.18-alpine3.18 As build

WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ /usr/local/app/

ARG ENVIRONMENT=production

RUN npm run build -- --configuration=${ENVIRONMENT}

FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/angular-app /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN sed -i s#MY_APP_API_URL#$API_URL#g /usr/share/nginx/html/main.*.js

COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

```
export const environment = {
    name: "development",
    production: false,
    baseApiUrl: 'MY_APP_API_URL',
   }
```

I added:

```
RUN sed -i s#MY_APP_API_URL#$API_URL#g /usr/share/nginx/html/main.*.js
```

based on this guide [dynamic API url](https://dev.to/felipewind/create-one-docker-image-of-angular-nginx-with-dynamic-api-url-57mi)

and receive the error:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/main.*.js: No such file or directory
```

The dockerfile works without that code but trying to during the docker runs being able to add my own api.

I have also tried this solution (similar question) [dynamically assign API URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215329/14933935) - no errors but it just defaults to the normal api url set in the file

TLDR;

- Want to have the ability to add my own api url when running the container
- Only using Dockerfile

Comment: Not a solution, but a possible way to debug this may be to run the container interactively and then try out the replacement there. If you can run it there, the same thing should work when using the dockerfile.

Comment: What you are doing is different from the blog post your point to. That will make the substitution at run time, but what you're doing will be applied at build time. Your approach is less flexible. In principle both are valid and can work. Depends on what you are ultimately wanting to do.